# Firebase/AngularJS limitToFirst(1) does not return a child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm using AngularJS and Firebase and trying to get the first child from a filtered set of children but limitToFirst(1) doesn't seem to get the first child like .child("=KDhddgd47nd") does

Like this

```
var Sport = new Firebase(FirebaseUrl);  
var Teams = Sport.child("teams");  
var myTeam = Teams.child("Saints");  
var myPlayers = myTeam.child("players").orderByChild("name");  
var myFixtures = myTeam.child("fixtures").startAt(now).orderByChild("date");
```

So I have a collection of fixtures now (myFixtures)

```
*var myFirstFixture = myFixtures.child("-KDUNN5KRNUmLlOhUB4D");*
```

works and gets the fixture where -KDUNN5KRNUmLlOhUB4D = the id of the fixture

**but**
    *`var myFirstFixture = myFixtures.limitToFirst(1);`*
does not get the same result, ie. doesn't get a fixture at all

It should though shouldn't it?

Comment: That depends on how you try to read data from it, which unfortunately you didn't add the code for. I'll write an educated guess to what you're doing, but can't be sure unless you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... Im preety sure you have to attach a call-back as this [doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/limittofirst.html) refers to.. May you try doing this and updating us with results?

```
var myFirstFixture = myFixtures.limitToFirst(1).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key() , snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: myFixtures.limitToFirst(1).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
            nextFixturesKey = snapshot.key();
            myFirstFixture = myTeam.child("fixtures").child(nextFixturesKey); 
            $scope.nextfixture = $firebaseArray(myFirstFixture);
 });

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess is that you're using:

```
$scope.fixture = $firebaseObject(myFirstFixture);
```

This will work when you have a direct `Firebase` reference to that first fixture, as when you do `myFixtures.child("-KDUNN5KRNUmLlOhUB4D")`.

It will however not work when you use a query. Since there may be multiple items that match your conditions, a query will *always* return a list of items. Even when there is only one matching fixture, the query will still result in a list of one fixture. So you'll need to map it to an array:

```
$scope.fixtures = $firebaseArray(myFirstFixture);
```

And then `ng-repeat` over it in your view HTML.